# php (web server) call java not working

Tags: java, php, centos

### Problem

- When call the java in php (web server), Out of Memory Error occurs.

### State

- web server - centos 6 , nginx, php-fpm , java
- call the java in centos - success
- call the java in php - Out of Memory Error occurs

### Call API

- Case : php

```
$string = exec('java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -jar /usr/share/nginx/html/my_test.jar /mytmp/testfile’, $output, $code);
```

- Case : centos 6 (linux)

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -jar /usr/share/nginx/html/my_test.jar /mytmp/testfile
```

### Error Message

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2673), pid=2549, tid=140226036020992
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_45-b14) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

### Question

- why different work ?
- how to solved that ?

### I try that (not solve)

- set memory

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx2g
```

Comment: How do you call your java application ?

Comment: "yum install java" - i installed on centos linux

Comment: I mean the complete code.

Comment: How many memory left on your system(before starting java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve thaht.
"**setsebool -P httpd_execmem on**"

Comment: After literally spending like 4 hours, this worked for me. I was trying to run libreoffice (which runs on java i guess) in PHP exec function and when it ran through http request, through nginx user I get Memory allocation error (mmap). Running same script from PHP Cli worked fine on Cent OS.